# Why won't the ImageView move?

Tags: android

I'm making a mobile game, and I want to make the ImageView move horizontally when I press the left and right buttons.

I've tried setX() and And Object Animator, but it still won't move

Left and right buttons.

```
        btnRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View right) {
                x++;
                ObjectAnimator d = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(first, "translationX", x);
                d.setDuration(2000);
                d.start();

            }
        });
        btnLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View left) {
                x--;
                ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(first, "translationX", x);
                animation.setDuration(2000);
                animation.start();

            }
        });
```

Imageview XML

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="166dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="168dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="471dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:contentDescription="@android:string/untitled"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.963"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />
```

When I used setX, the object would always move left if I pressed both buttons,and would stay there. When I use ObjectAnimator, it just stays there.

Comment: You're moving it by a pixel, you're not going to be able to see the delta, make it more exaggerated by increasing the delta value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectAnimator should be OK.
I tried your code and it works, but the translate distance is really small, I have to click the button many times to see an obvious movement.
You can change the `x++` to `x += 10` or even `x += 50` to check if it works actually.